# How can I remove residue left from peel and stick tiles?

Tags: tile, cleaning, adhesive, vinyl-flooring

I have old peel and stick vinyl tiles coming up off my vinyl flooring. I want to keep the floor underneath.

What gets rid of glue residue but is safe to use in house?

Comment: I've used soy based mastic removers before. The brand I used wad Bean-e-do

Answer (score 2):

The approach is usually progressive. You try a less aggressive cleaner to see if it works, and if not, then move on to a more aggressive. At some point, you may find that the cleaner damages the surface, so test in an inconspicuous area.

I would use paper towels and a mild scrubbing pad, and I would use cleaners in the following order:

- a soap based cleaner, such as Murphy's Oil Soap
- strong household cleaner with grease cutter, such as Formula 409
- a residue remover, such as Goo-Gone
- a mild solvent, such as denatured alcohol
- a stronger solvent, such as mineral spirits
- a mild stripper, such as a citrus based product
- a very strong solvent, such as acetone or lacquer thinner (but at this point you are almost sure to damage the surface of the flooring finish).

Comment: I tried wd 40 and it helps but stinks really bad and leaves sticky and oily residue

Comment: WD-40 is an example of a medium to strong solvent. I'm not sure why you would have started with that one...

Answer (score 2):

I have found an easy way if you are going to recover the floor with some other type of floor covering first i heat an iron and soften tile by laying iron over cloth so tile lifts easily then i sprinkle the floor with fine sawdust and rub in i leave the sawdust fir 15 minutes while lifting more tiles then brush off excess when completed the area i wish to work on i leave for half hour brush off again then vacuum and you are left with a clean floor with only very fine trace of sawdust

Comment: + for the sawdust idea.  I've used it so many times, and it works so well—but not to REMOVE the glue.. it just makes it non-sticky

Answer (score 0):

I pried up old peal and stick tile using heat gun, leaving very sticky glue residue, tried cleaning with hot water, mineral spirits and finally acetone. None worked. So finally I pealed off one tile and just sprinkled corn starch onto residue, making it no longer tacky at all. Not going to scrape anything as I plan on going over top of the concrete floor with floating click together vinyl.

Answer (score 0):

If you are leaving the tiles in place: peanut butter and a little rubbing. The only problem is it will remove the deep shine, in that area. Just give the flooring a little Mop & Glow..

Comment: OP said that they're removing the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the tiles, sprayed linoleum with Goo Gone,wiped up Goo Gone.  Lineoleum is clean. Quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying  apple cider vinegar to it and let it sit. Of that doesn't work get yourself some goof off. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a sticky floor issue after removing self stick 12x12 tiles. I took some advice and tried baking soda and it worked beautifully.

Comment: Nobody on this page appears to have suggested using baking soda. Can you explain how to use it, or at the very least link to where you found that advice? Thanks!